# SATA cable to USB 2.0 adapter

Tags: usb, nas, sata

I've purchased this case off of Newegg for my custom NAS: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816215244

This case has 4 SATA cable ports for each individual hard drive. **I'm looking for an SATA cable adapter that will work with USB 2.0**. The challenge I have found has been that there are plenty of SATA to USB solutions out there, but they include SATA cable and SATA power all on one cable.

My hard drives are powered through the two SATA power ports on the machine and hence do not need the power connection. Any advice?

**NOTE:** I fully understand the bottleneck from SATA to USB 2.0. This will just serve as a temporary solution for non-time sensitive tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an older model of this drive adapter:
[Newertech USB 3.0 Universal Drive Adapter](http://www.newertech.com/products/usb3_universaldriveadap.php)
[image: Newertech USB 3.0 Universal Drive Adapter]
which of course means mine is USB 2.0. The specifications on the web site indicate that the device will work with a USB 2.0 port.

The power supply to the hard drives is a separate set of components. As you note in your question, you already have power to your drive. You would need to connect only the data portion to the drive and the computer to accomplish your objective.

[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00506QPDU) has it for under US$35.00.